# SQL Server 2008 R2: IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Q 1**:
I have a empty table to insert records. Having one column of `IDENTITY` type, for which I want to insert values manually.

**Example**:

Table: Employee

```
create table Employee
(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar(255),
  Address varchar(255),
  City varchar(255)
 )
```

Inserting records:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee ON;
insert into Employee values(101,'ABC','XYZ','HighStreet','Moscow')
```

**Error**:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Employee' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

**Q 2**:

How to get latest inserted `ID` of an Employee without using `MAX` and `Top`?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omit the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1**

If you will try to insert the value into Identity column you will get the error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table ‘Employee’
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>
> Write SET IDENTITY_INSERT table name ON before the insert script and
>   SET IDENTITY_INSERT table name Off after insert script

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee ON
    insert into Employee(ID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values   
    (101,'ABC','XYZ','HighStreet','Moscow')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee OFF
```

**Answer 2**

There are several ways using like this after insert statement

> After an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk copy statement is completed,
>   @@IDENTITY contains the last identity value that is generated by the
>   statement

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

> It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection,
>   regardless of the table that produced the value, and regardless of the
>   scope of the statement that produced the value.

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

> It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection and by a
>   statement in the same scope, regardless of the table that produced the
>   value.

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘Employee’)
```

> It returns the last IDENTITY value produced in a table, regardless of
>   the connection that created the value, and regardless of the scope of
>   the statement that produced the value. IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by
>   scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT
>   returns the identity value generated for a specific table in any
>   session and any scope.

[MSDN SOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187342.aspx)

Comment: this answers OP question ,  does not address the error, I think this is what they were asking for - not 100% sure

Comment: you cant do --insert into Employee(myID,name) values( /* and have 5 values in here */)

Comment: I would recommend to **always** use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IDENT_CURRENT( 'table_name' )` to get the current value.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 0):

For external value of Identity column Column Name given explicitly is Must as below

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee ON;
insert into Employee(ID ,LastName,FirstName,Address,City)
values(101,'ABC','XYZ','HighStreet','Moscow')
```